# I overrided WM_CLOSE, how to came out from application now

Tags: mfc

I am a new bie to windows programming, I written an applicatoin with single dialog. In that I override  the CWnd::OnClose to do some stuff before exiting from application.after that I need to get out from application. But It will also be called if I post or send a message with WM_CLOSE event from overridden method, so how to get out from application now.

```
class MyDlg : public CDialogEx
{
public:
afx_msg void OnClose();
};

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(MyDlg , CDialogEx)
ON_WM_CLOSE ()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void MyDlg:: OnClose()
{
  //what code I should write here to exit from application. 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after you do your stuff write this:

```
__super::OnClose();
```

Comment: what is the meaning of _super here is it reference to the main window.

Comment: it is a "Microsoft specific" code that allows to call the base method. In standard c++ you would use: `CDialogEx::OnClose();` Microsoft provides you with a shortcut. You can even use `Defaut();` - another shortcut